# Is there an Excel Function to directly check the color of cell and return a logical TRUE or FALSE value to another Cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have put this function on Cell B2 to check the colour of A2 but it did not work.It should check if the colour is #A6A6A6, then return in to cell B2 as logical True False value. I use the german version of excel (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200).
My Code: `=WENN(FARBE(A2) = 10; WAHR; FALSCH)`

**I can not use any Makros because i would like to use it on M-Teams**

Comment: No is the answer. Even if you can do it with formulas you still gotta be needing `Excel Macro 4.0` i.e. `GET.CELL`. Also it is highly recommended by experts here to not use color as a reference to make logical calculations. Personally i never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure Excel, without VBA, you can't read the colour of a cell.

The best "workaround" is when your colours are caused by conditional formatting: in that case you can check the conditions, causing the colourisation and use that as an input for an `=IF()`-based formula (in your German-based Excel, that would be a `=WENN()`-based formula).

The result will be something like:

```
=WENN(ODER(WOCHENTAG(C10)=1; WOCHENTAG(C10)=7),"Wochenende","Arbeitstag")
```

Comment: @Blghn: can you check the formula I added to my answer?